Not able to run ACL Save on Redis
I am trying to run Redis locally on a Docker setup.
The setup with a Configuration and ACL File is as below:
# redis.conf
aclfile /var/lib/redis/users.acl
## cluster is not enabled

# users.acl
user default on >password ~* &* +@all

I then start redis using the docker-compose file:
version: "3.8"
services:
  redis_local:
    container_name: redis_local
    image: redis:6.2.2
    restart: always
    command: 
      -  /var/lib/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./redis.conf:/var/lib/redis/redis.conf
      - ./users.acl:/var/lib/redis/users.acl
      - ./redis_data:/data

All good so far.
All my ACL SETUSER commands work well and is creating users that can be authenticated.
However, I encounter an issue when running the ACL SAVE command.
Initially, I get this error:
Opening temp ACL file for ACL SAVE: Permission denied

Naturally, I tried to provide it permissions manually by running this command:
chmod 777 /var/lib/redis

But after I provide permissions to the folder using the above command and run ACL SAVE again, I get the following error:
Renaming ACL file for ACL SAVE: Device or resource busy

Does anyone have an idea on what can be done to fix this in a proper way? Any help in the matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Sorry for the late reply.
You need to set the owenership of the acl file to redis. Please use chown redis:redis /var/lib/redis/users.acl
